# Converting a state, ID and date formula to state sequence in traminer

Tags: r, traminer

```
 library(TraMineR)  



    df2 <- structure(list(ID = structure(c(1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", "4"), class = "factor"), 
    Date = structure(c(12432, 12432, 15262, 15293, 15385, 15385, 
    15475, 15567, 15598, 15628, 15689, 15810, 15871, 15963, 16024, 
    16054, 16144, 16205, 16297, 16389, 12432, 12492, 12614, 12676, 
    12767, 12888, 12949, 13071, 13132, 13253, 13344, 13406, 13436, 
    13559, 13618, 13709, 13771, 13862, 13953, 14045, 14137, 12432, 
    12676, 13010, 14045, 14137, 14228, 14290, 14410, 14502, 14563, 
    14714, 14744, 14744, 14775, 14836, 14897, 14897, 14928, 14958, 
    15048, 15201, 15232, 15323, 15414, 15536, 15536, 15536, 15567, 
    15567, 15598, 15628, 15659, 15659, 15751, 15751, 15779, 15810, 
    15810, 15840, 15871, 15871, 15901, 15901, 15963, 15993, 16054, 
    16054, 16085, 16116, 16144, 16144, 16175), class = "Date"), 
    st = structure(c(10L, 10L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 6L, 1L, 7L, 7L, 
    6L, 1L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 7L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 4L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 
    4L, 8L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 8L, 9L), .Label = c("1", "2", "3", 
    "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10"), class = "factor")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-93L), .Names = c("ID", "Date", "st"))
```

I can make an event sequence using:

```
ev <- seqecreate(id = df2$ID,timestamp = df2$Date,event = df2$st)
```

However, I'd like to get a state sequence for plotting. I could create the df2 into SPELL format by subtracting the dates etc, but then I'd loose the dates ( which I believe are better for plotting). Or can I convert the `ev` somehow into a state sequence?

Comment: Pls add 'library(traminer)' at the beginning of your snippets, so that people can directly see what you are referencing to

Comment: Please check the code you are providing. It generates errors: unknown objects `df2` and `ID` !!!

Comment: @Gilbert - Sorry. Believe it was due to the df being a tibble. converted now to regular dataframe. Hopefully it Works.

Comment: We still don't have the df2 object! Moreover, what kind of plotting would you like to do?

Comment: It works on my computer and also on other computers I´ve tried it on. Did you assign the structure/list into df2? df2<-structure(list ... copy from above).

Comment: Of course by assigning the structure to df2 I get an object df2. This was not what you had before your last edit!

Answer (score 0):

To plot your sequences you can do

```
seqpcplot(ev)
```

which gives you the following parallel coordinate plot

[image: seqpcplot]